# Improving write performance of ActiveMQ

Tags: performance, jms, activemq-classic

The code at https://github.com/maxant/share/blob/master/DBJMSPerf/src/JMSWriter.java writes BytesMessages to a local ActiveMQ server.

I only manage about 200 messages a second (< 5 milliseconds per message).

Using the code at https://github.com/maxant/share/blob/master/DBJMSPerf/src/DBWriter.java which follows a very similar pattern, I am able to write more than 500 messages a second to a database.

In both cases, I handle transactions myself, because I want to simulate committing after each message and I re-use the connection since I want to simulate connection pooling.

I use the persistent delivery mode in the JMS example because I am trying to analyse a design which has high availability - messages may not be lost.

At http://activemq.apache.org/performance.html they cite writing messages ten times faster than I am able to.

How can I improve the performance of the ActiveMQ server?

Comment: Using OpenMQ (https://mq.java.net/) the performance is even worse, letting me write about 150 messages per second.

Comment: Removing the persistent delivery mode and transactions from the JMSWriter improves performance so that it can write up to 300 messages per second, but still much less than advertised.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a connection pool to speedup performance as you re-create all the JMS resources per message you send, and that is slow.

The JMS based connection pools has very often built-in pooling of session/consumer/producers as well and hence you can keep the code as is.

Apache ActiveMQ has a pool you can use, and there is also one from the Spring Framework.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realise the Session and MessageProducer could also be pooled.  I added Apache commons-pool-1.6.jar and activemq-jms-pool-5.9.0.jar to the CP and these three lines of Code:
  
    PooledConnectionFactory pcf = new PooledConnectionFactory();
    pcf.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    pcf.start();
    final Connection connection = pcf.createConnection();

Performance is now about 300 messages a second.  Still much too slow, as far as I am concerned.

Comment: actually, after a few more tests, I'd say the performance was more like 400 messages a second.  But still nothing like the quoted figures.